# How to take a photo and pass it to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, photos

I want to take a photo using the device's camera.I want the image to be passed to another viewcontroller using segue.The image needs to be shown in the second viewcontroller only.But image needs to be saved to device's photo library.How can I acheive this using the imagepicker?

The code i've tried out is shown below

```
 func takePhoto(sender : UIButton)
 {
    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera))
    {
        if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil {
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
            presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: {})
        } else {
            print("Rear camera doesn't exist Application cannot access the camera.")
        }
    } else {
        print("Camera inaccessable Application cannot access the camera.")
    }

 }

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?)
{
    TakenImage = image
    let selectorToCall = Selector("imageWasSavedSuccessfully:didFinishSavingWithError:context:")
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(TakenImage!, self, selectorToCall, nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
    print("User canceled image")
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        // Anything you want to happen when the user selects cancel
    })
}
```

TakenImage is passed to next viewcontroller.But the image is not appearing there.The image is not saved library also

The code used for passing is shown below

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
    let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NoteDetailViewController") as! NoteDetailViewController
        controller.takinPhoto = true
        if(noteAlreadyEntered == true)
        {
            if (note != "")
            {
                controller.content = note
            }
            controller.takenImage = TakenImage
            if (self.tags != "")
            {
                controller.tagsTextField.text = self.tags
            }
        }
        else
        {
            controller.takenImage = TakenImage
            if (self.tags != "")
            {
                controller.tagsTextField.text = self.tags
            }
        }

    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: What part of this do you need help with? This question is far too broad. Please try something and update your question to be a single, focused issue that you need help with.

Comment: You can pass the image the same way you would pass an int ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage 
        self.imagePickerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

pass the image using prepareforsegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "yoursegueidentifier" {

            let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as! yourViewController
            dvc.image = image
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to identify first , if the image is clicked or selected from gallery . If clicked change bool value to yes and in that use underwritten code . This will save your image in gallery :

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

```
    imageCLicked  = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
```

let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageCLicked , 0.6)
        let compressedJPGImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        ALAssetsLibrary().writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedJPGImage!.CGImage, orientation: ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: compressedJPGImage!.imageOrientation.rawValue)!,
                                                       completionBlock:{ (path:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                                                        print("(path)")  //Here you will get your path
        })
}

Hope it works for you.